# how to use ImportValue in parameters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

As I knew, I can use [ImportValue](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-importvalue.html)  to reference value from another cloudformation stack in part of `Resources`.

```
NetworkInterfaces:
- GroupSet:
  - Fn::ImportValue:
      Fn::Sub: "${NetworkStackNameParameter}-SecurityGroupID"
  AssociatePublicIpAddress: 'true'
  DeviceIndex: '0'
  DeleteOnTermination: 'true'
  SubnetId:
    Fn::ImportValue:
      Fn::Sub: "${NetworkStackNameParameter}-SubnetID"
```

But seems this feature can't be used in `Parameters`

```
Parameters:
  VPC:
    Description: VPC ID
    Type: String
    Default:
      Fn::ImportValue:
        !Sub "${NetworkStackNameParameter}-VPC"
```

If I use above way, will get the error:

> An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateChangeSet operation: Template format error: Every Default member must be a string.

Anyway to work around? because the same vpc id, subnet id, security group Id, will be used not only one place.

#### updates

So I have to give up:

> 3. In your AWS CloudFormation template, confirm that the Parameters section doesn't contain any intrinsic functions.

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudformation-template-validation/

Comment: To start with your last statement (i.e. same values across stacks): Do you use [nested stacks](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-cfn-nested-stacks.html)?

Comment: can this VPC-related stack be used by multple application stacks?

Comment: I want to manage VPC stack seperately, because in most cases, it isn't changed.

Comment: @vahdet Whatever nested stacks or not, I can't use any `intrinsic functions` in Parameters session.

Answer (score 3):

One way of doing this is to use a condition:

```
Parameters:
  MyValue:
    Type: String
    Value: ''
Conditions:
  MyValueExists: !Not [ !Equals [!Ref MyValue, '']]
Resources:
  Resource:
    Type: AWS::Something
    Properties:
      Key: !If [MyValueExists, !Ref MyValue, !ImportValue 'Imported']
```