# How to import cloudformation stack output inside another stack parameter?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation

We are trying to import the output value of the base stack into the new stack **parameter** rather than the resource itself. Please help us to achieve that.

**BASE STACK** -
Below is the output defined in the base stack

```
Outputs:
    Asset:
        Value:
            Ref: Asset
        Export:
            Name:
                'Fn::Sub': '${AWS::StackName}-Asset'
```

We would like to import this value into the new stack but the CFN is throwing an error that Every ***Default member must be a string***.

**NEW STACK**

```
Parameters:
    BaseStackNameParameter:
        Type: String
        Default: assetstack
        
    AssetVal:
        Type: String
        Default: !ImportValue
                  'Fn::Sub': '${BaseStackNameParameter}-Asset'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to use ImportValue in parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60446398/how-to-use-importvalue-in-parameters)

Comment: Hey, @Paolo thanks for the suggested post. The question is almost similar but doesn't have an answer. Therefore that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Yes, it does have an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63691486/3390419 , and it's exactly what you want to do

Comment: By answer, I meant an accepted answer. Not the general answer. Also, my motive is to import the value in the parameter itself, not the resources. which I don't see happening in the shared link answer.

Answer (score 1):

The error is correct. You **can't do this**. Such functionality is not supported by CloudFormation.

Comment: Thanks, Marcin for the info, but is there any alternate solution? This question is in succession to my previous question i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/q/71908962/9548311

Comment: @NitinGarg You have to use `ImportValue` in your resources, not `Parameters`. If you require other functionality, CloudFormation may be the wrong tool for your job.